# Add new row but change one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of data like this:

```
 ID     |  Spend
 0001   |  250
 0002   |  500
 0003   |  900
```

I need to copy each row and but change the spend in each row for tax so it will look this this:

```
 ID     |  Spend
 0001   |  250
 0001   |  200
 0002   |  500
 0002   |  450
 0003   |  900
 0003   |  850
```

Can anyone advise on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `union all`:

```
select id, spend
from t
union all
select id, spend - 50
from t
order by id;
```